# php, how to find and copy specific line(s)/rows of 2 dimensional array into another array for processing

Tags: php

sorry, my brain doesn't do arrays, pointers and oop - so far i managed to cope with simple 1-line 'record' type arrays and old structured programming methods.

BUT i now need to deal with a 2-dimensional table type array following a mysql query.

here is what i need to do:

1. get mysql returned records in array to another array eg.

   ```
      while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result_35bid, MYSQL_BOTH) )  //-- done
      {
   ```
2. copy $row to another array;

   ```
                        $rowcopy = array();
            $rowcopy = $row;             //-- i think i have done ok
   ```
3. now i need to find all a specific value contained in a field name 'domname' and copy this row/line to another array. so how do i do this?? from my $rowcopy to a new array. so, i need to find every row that has a field value say 'mydomain' from the field name domname and copy this into the new array, $newArray.

i have tried this but it fails:

```
           $newArray = array();
       $newline = 0;
        for( $i = 0; $i < count($rowcopy); $i++ )
        {

            if ( $rowcopy['domname'] == 'mydomain'  )
            {
                $newline ++;

                   $newArray[$newline] = $rowcopy[$I];
                                   //-- copy this row to new array

                                   //-- i think my problem is here ??

            }

        } // end-for

    print_r($newArray);

       } // end-while
```

this should result in a subset of the $rowcopy containing all records/rows that have a field value 'mydomain' in the field/key 'domname' to the new smaller array, $newArray.

[ in. mysql terms, i need to find all records that conatin a certain domain name - but this i need to do in php using arrays as this is a follow on from a mysql query alreday performed ]

any help appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the part of the row retrievement from the database, you can check, if your current row contains your specified content. If it's so, then you can use the array_push().

```
$result = array();
while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result_35bid, MYSQL_BOTH) {
      if($row['domain'] == 'mydomain') {
            array_push($result, $row);
      }
}
```

See [PHP.net - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result_35bid, MYSQL_BOTH) {
      if($row['domain'] == 'mydomain') {
            $result[] = $row;
      }
}
```

you will get an array of rows where domain is 'mydomain'
also you can do:

```
$result = array();
while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result_35bid, MYSQL_BOTH) {
      if($row['domain'] == 'mydomain') {
            $result[$row['domain']][] = $row;
      }
}
```

you will get array with domain names as keys and array of rows as values. In other words, you will sort rows by domain name

PS: I think you don't need MYSQL_BOTH. And also do not use mysql_ functions. Use mysqli_ or PDO instead.

Comment: i need to understand multi dimensonal arrays - but my logic here wasn't much good. i managed to do a mysql query with 2-sorts, so now ii dont need to do further processing in php. the 2-sorts mysql query involed was: SELECT * FROM auction WHERE bidderemail='$uemail' AND txtype='$txtype' ORDER BY domain, bidamount DESC ";
** notice the two field names separated by comma following ORDER BY .